# Can I Install ext4 via Debian 6.0.2 and update for stability?

Tags: debian-squeeze, ext4

I am installing Debian 6.0.2.1 (because that's the CD I found in my CD wallet and I don't want to wait to download a newer version *[6.5 is newest at time of writing]*). I am choosing ext4 for my FS; once the install is complete I will update all the packages and compile a 3.x kernel.

Is the ext4 code and binaries included in earlier version of Debian Squeeze (like 6.0.2.1) considered stable, and if not, when I `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` will this also update and upgrade the ext4 tools and code on the system bringing me up to a stable deployment of ext4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically 6.0.2.1 and 6.0.5 are the same when it comes to ext4. Debian stable branch won't do any major upgrades, only critical security fixes and stuff like that will be backported.

The ext4 binaries in Debian 6 are considered stable, just don't expect them to be latest-and-greatest since that's not the way Debian stable rolls.